# MySQL insert unique record by index of columns

Tags: mysql, insert, indexing, unique

I have a table:

```
table user(
  id_user,
  userName,
  email,
  primary key(id_user)
);
```

I added unique index on it:

```
alter table user add unique index(userName, email);
```

Now I have two indexs on the table:

```
Index:
Keyname     Unique      Field   
PRIMARY     Yes         id_user
userName    Yes         userName, email
```

The task is to find the MySQL statement for fastest way to insert new **unique** record. 
Statement should return `Id_user` of the new or existent record.

I'm considering these 2 options, and don't know which is better or is there some third better  way to do this?:

1.

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`userName`, `email`)
VALUES (u1,'u1@email.me' )
ON DUPLICATE KEY Ignore
```

Q: Where in this statement should be specified that the required KEY for unique inserts is Keyname = uesrName?

2.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT `userName`, `email` FROM user WHERE `userName` = u1 AND `email` = u1@email.me)
BEGIN

END
ELSE
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO user(`userName`, `email`)
      VALUES (u1, u1@email.me);
END IF;
```

Q: In this statement - how the index with Keyname = userName should be taken in consideration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get data out of a table in MySQL is to select.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION ForceUser(pUsername varchar(255), pEmail varchar(255)) 
RETURNS integer
BEGIN
  DECLARE MyId INTEGER;

  /*First do a select to see if record exists:*/
  /*because (username,email) is a unique key this will return null or a unique id.*/
  SELECT id INTO MyId FROM user 
  WHERE username = pUsername 
    AND email = pEmail;
  IF MyId IS NULL THEN 
    /*If not then insert the record*/
    INSERT INTO user (username, email) VALUES (pUserName,pEmail);
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO MyId;
  END IF;
  RETURN MyID;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

> Q: Where in this statement should be specified that the required KEY for unique inserts is Keyname = uesrName?

A: MySQL already knows this, because that information is part of the table definition.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html